# Work of form action ./login and onsubmit keyword

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

> Please explain the piece of code below, emphasize on ./login and onsubmit keywords..

```
<form action="./login" onsubmit ="return validatedata()" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `form` tag of `HTML` language. It says following things:

1. content of this form (such as `Text Box` or `Radio Button` or `Combo Box` or other `HTML` component values) send to `./login` url. It is better use `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()` for set relative path rather of absolute path.
2. `onsubmit ="return validatedata()"` part says: When user click on submit button(with any label) before submit form to `./login` url, execute `validatedata` function in `Java Script` functions, if this function not existed , user get a java script error(or other script languages).
3. method="post" part says: this form send with `POST` method . please see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html for more information.

for more information related to `form` tag see : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Answer (score 0):

This declares an HTML `<form>` element. When submitting the form it will call the javascript function validatedata(). If the function return true the form will be submitted and if it return false, it won't. The './login' is the destination of the form data. So there is probably a page handling the url `http://<your_site>/<where_you_currently_are>/login`. It also  depends on the technology you use. I don't know if you use a framework such as Struts or if you only use JSPs as is.